# Google Scholar profile scraping

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, google-scholar

I'm trying to retrieve the links of a Google Scholar user's work from their profile but am having trouble accessing the html that is hidden behind the "show more" button. I would like to be able to capture all the links from a user but currently can only get the first 20. Im using the following script to scrape for reference.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests 

author_url = 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ'

html_content = requests.get(author_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content.text, 'lxml')
tables = soup.final_all('table)
table = tables[1]
rows = table.final_all('tr')

links = []
for row in rows:
  t = row.find('a')
  if t is not None:
    links.append(t.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of obtaining that data:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm ## if Jupyter notebook: from tqdm.notebook import tqdm

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

big_df = pd.DataFrame()
headers = {
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'x-requested-with': 'XHR',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)

payload = {'json': '1'}

for x in tqdm(range(0, 500, 100)):
    url = f'https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&cstart={x}&pagesize=100'
    r = s.post(url, data=payload)
    soup = bs(r.json()['B'], 'html.parser')
    works = [(x.get_text(), 'https://scholar.google.com' + x.get('href')) for x in soup.select('a') if 'javascript:void(0)' not in x.get('href') and len(x.get_text()) > 7]
    df = pd.DataFrame(works, columns = ['Paper', 'Link'])
    big_df = pd.concat([big_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(big_df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
100%
5/5 [00:03<00:00, 1.76it/s]
Paper   Link
0   Latent dirichlet allocation https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=mG4imMEAAAAJ:IUKN3-7HHlwC
1   On spectral clustering: Analysis and an algorithm   https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=mG4imMEAAAAJ:2KloaMYe4IUC
2   ROS: an open-source Robot Operating System  https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=mG4imMEAAAAJ:u-x6o8ySG0sC
3   Rectifier nonlinearities improve neural network acoustic models https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=mG4imMEAAAAJ:gsN89kCJA0AC
4   Recursive deep models for semantic compositionality over a sentiment treebank   https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=mG4imMEAAAAJ:_axFR9aDTf0C
... ... ...
473 A Sparse Sampling Algorithm for Near-Optimal Planning in Large Markov Decision Processes    https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&cstart=400&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=mG4imMEAAAAJ:hMod-77fHWUC
474 On Discrim inative vs. Generative   https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&cstart=400&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=mG4imMEAAAAJ:qxL8FJ1GzNcC
475 Game Theory with Restricted Strategies  https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&cstart=400&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=mG4imMEAAAAJ:8k81kl-MbHgC
476 Exponential family sparse coding with application to self-taught learning with text documents   https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&cstart=400&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=mG4imMEAAAAJ:LkGwnXOMwfcC
477 Visual and Range Data   https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=mG4imMEAAAAJ&cstart=400&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=mG4imMEAAAAJ:eQOLeE2rZwMC
478 rows × 2 columns
```

See pandas documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Also Requests docs: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For BeautifulSoup, go to https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

And for TQDM visit https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/